# Web config redirect rule to the same action with another query string parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, web-config

Well, in my C# ASP .Net MVC application I have an URL:

```
controller/action?parameter=value
```

I need to redirect this URL in `web.config` using rewrite rules to:

```
controller/action?parameter=anotherValue
```

I've already configured the necessary section like below:

```
<rule name="Redirect" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="controller/action?parameter=value" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="controller/action?parameter=anotherValue" />
</rule>
```

But this rule just doesn't work. Also I've tried:

```
<rule name="Redirect" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="controller/action$" />
    <conditions>  
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="parameter=value" />  
    </conditions> 
    <action type="Redirect" url="controller/action?parameter=anotherValue" redirectType="Permanent" />
```

but this rule redirects me to: `controller/action?parameter=value&parameter=anotherValue`

**How can I correctly perform this redirection?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?` sign on your first rule is problematic, since it's a `Wildcard` character.

Try to add `appendQueryString="false"` to your second rule:

```
<rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="controller/action$" />
    <conditions>  
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="parameter=value" />  
    </conditions> 
    <action type="Redirect" url="controller/action?parameter=anotherValue" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks for advice but still nothing. The same behavior.

Comment: I just tried it on my local IIS and it does work. please note that i revised my answer and removed the redundant `patternSyntax="Wildcard"`.

Comment: I removed `patternSyntax="Wildcard"` and it worked... Thanks!